# What does this mean?

Tags: clash-of-clans

After the new update, while watching a live replay, the spectators are also shown but today the game showed the spectators like this:-

[image: Spectators]

Wasn't it supposed to show 3 spectators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that one viewer is from defenders clan and two viewers from attackers clan.
 Hence they are being more precise than just showing three spectators.

Answer (score 0):

This happened as you were 1 of the spectators and the other 2 are the other people watching the game

Comment: Isn't the left number the # of spectators from the defender's team while the right number is the # of spectators on the attacker's team.